# IndexOutOfBoundException when trying trying to get a .ods cell with jOpenDocument

Tags: java, jopendocument

I am facing a little challenge with my coding.

```
File file = new File("template.ods");
Sheet sheet;
try {
    // load file
    sheet = SpreadSheet.createFromFile(file).getSheet("Certificate");
    System.out.println(file);
    System.out.println(sheet.getCellAt("A1").isEmpty());
    sheet.setValueAt("A1", 1, 1);;
    System.out.println(sheet.getCellAt(1, 1).getTextValue());
    sheet.getCellAt(2, 2).setValue("B2");
    sheet.getCellAt(3, 3).setValue("C3");
    sheet.getCellAt(4, 4).setValue("D4");
    // Save to file and open it.
    File outputFile = new File("fillingTest.ods");
    OOUtils.open(sheet.getSpreadSheet().saveAs(outputFile));

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting to know the jOpenDocument-Library. I want to fill an existing OpenOffice-Spreadsheet-Template (template.ods) with some sample values.
When running the above code, the console shows this:

> template.ods
> true
>
> ```
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
>     at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>     at org.jopendocument.dom.spreadsheet.Table.getRow(Unknown Source)
>     at org.jopendocument.dom.spreadsheet.Table.getImmutableCellAt(Unknown Source)
>     at org.jopendocument.dom.spreadsheet.Table.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
>     at org.jopendocument.dom.spreadsheet.Table.setValueAt(Unknown Source)
>     at jOpenDocument.createDocument.main(createDocument.java:48)
> ```

*"template.ods"* and *"true"* shows that the application retrieved the file from directory and *"true"* that it could read the cell, which is empty.

But I don't know which Array throws the Exception and why it says *"Unknown Source"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array of rows throws the exception. Try adding more rows with `sheet.setRowCount()` before setting cell contents.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ensureRowCount, which is more appropriate in my opinion:

```
sheet.ensureRowCount(row);
```